# rails start a new project with large portions of an existing app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, project, ruby-on-rails-3.2

What would be the best way to create a new rails app based on code from an existing app I've written before ( lots of initializer, config things setup correctly )

I find it almost undoable in rails to make a clean copy of my existing app and use that as base for a new one.

Should I start from scratch? and then later review the initializers and copy changed portions over? Seems thats the only way to go without having all kind of issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way to go is make a copy of your app, and empty out most of app/controllers, app/models, and app/views.

I suggest you create an empty project.  Then make a copy of your app, and replace the app directory (in your copy) with the app directory from the empty project.

Comment: Ok I just added parts from the other app in step by step guess that's one of the better ways to do it. Or use rails templates for new projects but I don't have that much that its worth to invest time in that.